# What can be best database schema for multiple project and one database?

Tags: database-design, schema, mysql-5.7, table, erd

I am working on multiple projects but the back-end will remain the same. I have a different server for auth, data, etc. and one database to store all the details.

If one projects are creating any data then only that project can access that data and others project shouldn't access that. 
For example, if users saving some data in the application from one app that only that app can access that.

I am trying to find the Schema for this database. I am using MySQL 5.7 database.

I am not looking for the multitenant approach of storing the data.

I am looking to store the data in JSON datatype.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Is this a matter of the projects can all use the same database structure (all tables and columns)? the same core (some tables are of use to all projects, others are unique)? Or, are the projects completely independent (no significant overlap in tables and columns)? It sounds like you may want to look for other questions, tagged `multi-tenant`, for ideas on different entities sharing the same database/server, but not being able to see each other's data.

Comment: I don't want a multi-tenant. I need to build the table with JSON datatype in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about [Multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy), or multiple separate entities sharing code, but having its own dataset. While there are many ways to approach this, the most simple way to approach this is by **creating multiple databases (schemas), where each project only has access to its own, separate database**.

If the amount of data that each user creates is very small, it can make sense to use a single table or set of tables, where each one is **prefixed by a user id, or user field**, so the applications controls you can only write and read your own rows. That assumes that you ha full control the application.

If the application is on the user's side, you shouldn't solve this on MySQL only- **you need a [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends)** application communicating to the user's frontend application, and being between the database and the frontend application for access control (implementing [authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) and [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication)).

Answer (score 0):

Each user in the `mysql` need permissions `GRANT`ed by the corresponding query.

Usually `GRANT` is used in the form of:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.`myscheme` TO `user`@`host` IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword'
```

But you can prepend the names of the tables, routines and functions by some prefix accordingly to the project they belongs to. And then grant permissions for specific user to that tables and routines only:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON projA25_*.`myscheme` TO `pA25`@`host` IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON projB17_*.`myscheme` TO `pB17`@`host` IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword'
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is indeed a multi tenant setup, now whether to have multiple databases or just one or few shared database depends on factors like how much data each tenant in your system going to have in foreseeable future.

I worked on shared databases hosting data for 100's of tenants with small to medium capacity efficiently. This approach has lots of advantages including saving costs on resources and increased performance in some of scenarios.

Here's a simple example of how shared multi tenant shared database would work,

[image]

[Multi-tenant applications with elastic database tools and row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-elastic-tools-multi-tenant-row-level-security)